# AWS Amplify CLI: An error occurred when pushing the resources to the cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I'm trying to upload some changes to a lambda function to the backend using amplify push. I've used it quite a few times with no issues whatsoever, but all of a sudden I've been getting errors and cannot push resources to the cloud

The errors happen after the following gets done:

```
Successfully pulled backend environment dev from the cloud.
```

I've been getting various error messages. This is the first:

```
Command failed with exit code 1: C:\Users\Name\go\bin\build-lambda-zip.exe -o H:\Documents\React 
JS\ihubdashboard\amplify\backend\function\testgo\dist\latest-build.zip H:\Documents\React 
JS\ihubdashboard\amplify\backend\function\testgo\bin\main
failed to compress file: open H:\Documents\React 
JS\ihubdashboard\amplify\backend\function\testgo\bin\main: The system cannot find the file specified.
An error occurred during the push operation: Command failed with exit code 1: 
C:\Users\Name\go\bin\build-lambda-zip.exe -o H:\Documents\React 
JS\ihubdashboard\amplify\backend\function\testgo\dist\latest-build.zip H:\Documents\React 
JS\ihubdashboard\amplify\backend\function\testgo\bin\main
failed to compress file: open H:\Documents\React 
JS\ihubdashboard\amplify\backend\function\testgo\bin\main: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

This was the other:

```
Command failed with exit code 1: C:\Users\Name\go\bin\build-lambda-zip.exe -o H:\Documents\React 
JS\ihubdashboard\amplify\backend\function\completeregistration\dist\latest-build.zip 
H:\Documents\React JS\ihubdashboard\amplify\backend\function\completeregistration\bin\main
failed to compress file: open H:\Documents\React 
JS\ihubdashboard\amplify\backend\function\completeregistration\bin\main: The system cannot find the 
file specified.
An error occurred during the push operation: Command failed with exit code 1: 
C:\Users\Name\go\bin\build-lambda-zip.exe -o H:\Documents\React 
JS\ihubdashboard\amplify\backend\function\completeregistration\dist\latest-build.zip 
H:\Documents\React JS\ihubdashboard\amplify\backend\function\completeregistration\bin\main
failed to compress file: open H:\Documents\React 
JS\ihubdashboard\amplify\backend\function\completeregistration\bin\main: The system cannot find the 
file specified.

Command failed with exit code 1: go get -u github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/cmd/build-lambda-zip
# cd C:\Users\Name\go\src\github.com\aws\aws-lambda-go; git pull --ff-only
fatal: Unable to create 'C:/Users/Name/go/src/github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/.git/ORIG_HEAD.lock': File 
exists.
```

This is the current error message I am getting:

```
If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a
git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git
process is running and remove the file manually to continue.
package github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/cmd/build-lambda-zip: exit status 128
An error occurred during the push operation: Command failed with exit code 1: go get -u 
github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/cmd/build-lambda-zip
# cd C:\Users\Name\go\src\github.com\aws\aws-lambda-go; git pull --ff-only
fatal: Unable to create 'C:/Users/Name/go/src/github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/.git/ORIG_HEAD.lock': File 
exists.

If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a
git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git
process is running and remove the file manually to continue.
package github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/cmd/build-lambda-zip: exit status 128
```

Anybody experience this before? Or know what to do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be a bug - will be fixed. More details can be found in the following:

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/6679

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/6693